# Table stretches if using rowspan and fixed heights, depending on given rows

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, html-table

I have two tables, one with 4 rows, one with three.
Each ist build with fixed width and height on it's cells.

The outcome is different: the version with 4 lines has it's cells stretched in FF and IE, while the Version with 3 lines is working fine.

Both samples are looking good in Chrome. 
What's going wrong here??

http://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/mrg4L2vt/

```
4-row-table:

<table>
<tr bgcolor="#555">
    <td style="width:100px; height:50px" colspan="2">2 Breit</td>
    <td style="width:50px; height:100px" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
    <td style="width:50px; height:100px" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#555">
    <td style="width:50px; height:100px" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
    <td style="width:50px; height:100px" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#555">
    <td style="width:50px; height:100px" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
    <td style="width:50px; height:100px" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#555">
    <td style="width:100px; height:50px" colspan="2">2 Breit</td>
</tr>
</table>


3-row-table:

<table>
<tr bgcolor="#555">
    <td style="width:100px; height:50px" colspan="2">2 Breit</td>
    <td style="width:50px; height:100px" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
    <td style="width:50px; height:100px" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#555">
    <td style="width:50px; height:100px" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
    <td style="width:50px; height:100px" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
</tr>

<tr bgcolor=#555>
    <td style="width:100px; height:50px" colspan="2">2 Breit</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Oh, and btw: it's currently no option to re-build the whole thing with divs if possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm the behaviour with Firefox and I have no idea why it occurs, but I've found a fix that appears to work:

https://jsfiddle.net/mcwjtotn/

```
4-row-table:

<table style="width:218px; height:215px;">
  <tr style="height:25%" bgcolor="#555555">
    <td style="width:50%" colspan="2">2 Breit</td>
    <td style="width:25%" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
    <td style="width:25%" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="height:25%" bgcolor="#555555">
    <td style="width:25%;" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
    <td style="width:25%" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="height:25%" bgcolor="#555555">
    <td style="width:25%" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
    <td style="width:25%" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="height:25%" bgcolor="#555555">
    <td style="width:50%" colspan="2">2 Breit</td>
  </tr>
</table>

3-row-table:

<table style="width:218px; height:160px;">
  <tr style="height:33.33%" bgcolor="#555555555">
    <td style="width:50%" colspan="2">2 Breit</td>
    <td style="width:25%" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
    <td style="width:25%" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="height:33.33%" bgcolor="#555555">
    <td style="width:25%" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
    <td style="width:25" rowspan="2">2 Hoch</td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="height:33.33%" bgcolor="#555555">
    <td style="width:50%" colspan="2">2 Breit</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Rather than setting the width and height for each element of the table, I've set the width and height for the entire table and the used percentages to defines the sizes of individual elements. This produces the same results under Firefox and Chrome.

The values for width and height take into account the gaps between elements in the original but the resulting tables will actually be a tiny bit different than your original tables but will be consistent across browsers.

EDIT: I've updated the code to work with IE 11 as well. IE 11 needs the height of the rows to be defined independently and also requires full length colour values.

Comment: Looks promising! I will give it a try on a  real data table!

Comment: Hmmm, it really looks good with FF and Chrome - but it's totally destroyed in IE 11

Comment: The original that you posted looks totally wrong in IE as well, though. Is there more style code that I'm missing?

Comment: yeah, and that's already wrong. Unfortunatly your fix does work for FF and looks the same now as in Chrome, but it does not work for  IE.

Comment: Ah ha! I've found how IE 11 likes it to be. Still works with Firefox and Chrome. Editing answer now.

Comment: How did you find this out? This is soooo crazy and I was already running out of ideas!! But this now works like a charm. AMAZING!! Thank you so much for your help!!